# Route planning option for a website

Tags: php, html, css, web, https

I need to have a route planning option in my website. It must be given route alternatives when the user enter origin and destination.
Look for this example https://www.transitbangkok.com/ 
 Can someone help Please

Comment: Elaborate your question, be more specific and give examples.

Comment: So building a Google map-ish site, that is too broad for SO.

Answer (score 0):

Transitbangkok does not provide an API. So you can not embed it easily into your site or use their API to perform some search queries.